# Editing an element with .html() and applying a handler with .click() in one statement

Tags: jquery

In jQuery I am often writing pairs of statements to alter a button and its event like:

```
$("#button-container").html("<img id='button' src='button.png'>");
$("#button").click(buttonFunction);
```

Am I missing some obvious/easy way to do this in one line, like in:

```
$("#button-container").html("<img id='button' src='button.png'>").click(buttonFunction);
```

?

Comment: If one element is contained in the other, you can use DOM traversal methods to easily chain them together.  How you do so depends on your HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working from jdavies' answer, I like to do the following to improve readability (and editability) as much as possible:

```
$('<img/>').attr({
        id: 'button',
        src: 'button.png'
    })
    .click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    })
    .appendTo('#button-container');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, however I'm not sure you gain much in terms of readability:

```
$("#button-container").append($("<img id='button' src='button.png'>").click(buttonFunction));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ax79h/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for it to automatically hook up the event for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('#button').live('click', buttonFunction);
});
```

Then you only have to do the HTML updating. But, this only helps when you have multiple similar events otherwise you're going to have just as much code, just in different places.

Comment: This could work for me. I'll have to switch from modifying #button in-place to hiding/showing the correct buttons, but that's not difficult and I think makes the code more elegant overall.

Comment: `.delegate()` is much better in most situations (like this one).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button-container").html("<img id='button' src='button.png'>");
$("#button").click(buttonFunction);
```

Can change to:

```
$("#button-container").html("<img id='button' src='button.png'>").find('#button').click(buttonFunction);
```

But it's not a whole lot more elegant.

Comment: Right, it's one statement but I guess there is no elegant way around the fact that .html() doesn't return the element it modifies.

Comment: `.html(string)` *does* return the jQuery object it modifies. It does not, however, return its contents.